# WebGLRenderer Error: Error creating WebGL context in chrome Version 83.0.4103.106

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, webgl, intel

When I open 'https://get.webgl.org/' on Chrome I get below error in console and don't see rotating cube but it works in Firefox on the same system.

#### Console Error:

WebGLRenderer Error: Error creating WebGL context.

#### Configurations:

- **Chrome**: Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- **OS**: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763)
- **GPU1**:Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
- **GPU2**:Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620

It seems something is wrong with `chrome (83.0.4103.106)` in combination with `Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620` GPUs.
Anyone know of anything to help?

PS:
[Result of https://get.webgl.org/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqj9h.png)

#### Update

about:gpu ->  https://github.com/sanjeev-aeon/s3/blob/master/gpu.txt

### Answer

Checked "about:policy" and found `Disable3DAPIs` was set `true` and was blocking WebGL.

Comment: Most likely your GPU has been banned by chrome because of security issues in the driver. Are you running the lastest drivers? about:gpu might have more info.

Comment: This is what I thought and enabled  --ignore-gpu-blacklist flag. Still does not work.

Comment: You comment seems unrelated to what I wrote.

Comment: The driver's version is  26.20.100.6860 (which is not latest).  I've requested for about:gpu log.

Comment: And have you tried upgrading to the latest driver? That's the most likely thing to fix it. As for about:gpu you just type it in your chrome's url bar

Comment: Here is the about:gpu log -> https://github.com/sanjeev-aeon/s3/blob/master/gpu.txt